# What is a Texan Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Texan Word™.  

Each Word™ can be tested by itself. This is not a definitive list of Texan Words™.

---

| Texan Words™ | Not Texan Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| EGOTIST | BRAGGART |
| FALSETTO | SOPRANO |
| FORESTRY | SAWMILL |
| FUNGOID | ANTIFUNGAL |
| GUILTY | INNOCENT |
| GUNPOINT | THREATEN |
| KATYDID | CRICKET |
| NUDITY | BARENESS |
| PINPOINT | LOCATE |
| PORTFOLIO | ENVELOPE |
| SKULL | PELVIS |
| QUIETEST | STILLEST |
| QUINTUPLET | OFFSPRING |
| YOGURT | YOGHURT |

Here is the CSV version:

```
Texan Words™, Not Texan Words™
EGOTIST, BRAGGART
FALSETTO, SOPRANO
FORESTRY, SAWMILL
FUNGOID, ANTIFUNGAL
GUILTY, INNOCENT
GUNPOINT, THREATEN
KATYDID, CRICKET
NUDITY, BARENESS
PINPOINT, LOCATE
PORTFOLIO, ENVELOPE
SKULL, PELVIS
QUIETEST, STILLEST
QUINTUPLET, OFFSPRING
YOGURT, YOGHURT
```

---

Hints will be released once or twice daily.

Hint 1:

> "Texan" refers to something from Texas (in more ways than one).

Hint 2:

> You're gonna need a calculator for this one.

Hint 3:

> Alternate titles include Instrumental Words™ and Calculable Words™.

Hint 4:

> No need to use the ALPHA button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think a Texan word is

> A word that can be "evaluated" on a Texas Instruments calculator.

How it works:

> After pressing the required keys to spell out the word (without ALPHA) and then pressing enter, they do not give errors, unlike the non-Texan words. Most of them end with functions that are missing their arguments.

Comment: I believe it's more like rot13(n frevrf bs yrggref juvpu, jura cerffrq ba n GV pnyphyngbe jvgubhg gur NYCUN ohggba, cebqhprf n "inyvq" (pna or pnyphyngrq) zngurzngvpny rkcerffvba. Sbe rknzcyr, PEVPXRG qbrfa'g penfu sbe zr, ohg vg qbrf abg cebqhpr nalguvat erzbgryl rinyhnoyr.) Either way, very nice find!

Comment: I do think rot13(zbfg rkcerffvbaf znqr ol gur aba-grkna jbeqf jvyy raq hc zvffvat nethzragf, naq gurersber va reebef.) And thanks !

Comment: Yay, nice job! Continuing the conversation above, rot13(gur O naq P xrlf jrer sbeovqqra fvapr nccf naq cebtenzf jbhyq inel sebz pnyphyngbe gb pnyphyngbe, urapr jul PEVPXRG vf Aba-Grkna ohg zvtug abg or qlfshapgvbany.)